# Should I normalise my dependent variable by a measured variable that I want to be constant?

Tags: t-test, sampling, multiple-comparisons, measurement-error, type-i-and-ii-errors

This is a question about the validity of applying the results of a statistical test, and unfortunately will require some explanation of the experiment in question.

Essentially, I want to measure how well different bacterial cells stick to glass. This involves preparing one set of cells to fluoresce red, and different set of cells to fluoresce green. I then mix the two together, and add the mixture to a glass slide, which I then wash. I then count the number of red and green cells that I can see on the glass - the resulting ratio is my dependent variable. However, because cells can behave weirdly, and because I have to be able to assume that the sample I apply to the glass originally has the same concentration of each cell type, I also add the sample to a pad that allows me to count the number of each cell type (red or green) without the stickier cells being more abundant. Biologically, I would argue that if the ratio on the pad is significantly different from 1, then I can't make valid conclusions from any of my data.
My colleague wants to measure the ratio of cells on the pads, and calculate a mean from this, and then use this ratio to adjust the ratio we calculate from cells on the glass slides. I don't think this is mathematically valid. We are currently performing an initial test to check that the ratios don't differ from one (which comes with its own problems of false positives), and only if they are all ~1 do we proceed with comparisons of the ratios on the glass. I think that, given we have just concluded that the ratio of cells in the mixture is not different from 1, we shouldn't then correct for the actual observed ratio, which will be similar to 1 but not exactly. In my opinion this undermines the whole purpose of checking that the original ratio could have been drawn from a population of mean 1. The whole idea of sampling errors is that the measurements I take may not be exactly the same as the properties of the underlying population.

So, my question is - how should I approach analysing this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Biologically, I would argue that if the ratio on the pad is significantly different from 1, then I can't make valid conclusions from any of my data.

That depends on what you are assuming about the processes that lead to bacteria sticking on the glass plate. If there is no competition or cooperation among bacteria for sticking to the plate, so that the probability of a bacterium's sticking is simply determined by its own characteristics, then there might be no problem at all. That could be the case even if the red/green ratio on the pad (without washing) is far from 1.

Under that assumption, you could use the numbers of each type of bacterium found on the pad (without washing) to calculate the numbers applied to the glass plate before washing. You could then, for each type, take the ratio of those remaining after washing to the number applied as a measure of the probability of sticking. That would allows you to correct for (perhaps unavoidable) differences in preparing the strains of each color/phenotype of bacteria and give you better estimates of the actual probabilities of sticking. In situations where that type of independence among outcomes holds that's often a good idea, provided that you can get precise enough estimates of the starting numbers/concentrations. It's the practical, not the statistical, "significance" of the red-green difference that matters.

If the red/green ratio on the pad is much different from 1, however, you might want to use that as a quality-control warning. Look more closely into the reasons that might be the case, and whether those reasons might affect your ability to interpret the results properly.

If the sticking process is more complex and bacteria don't behave independently of each other (e.g., if the bacteria are on the glass plate long enough to form biofilms before you wash it), your concern might be warranted.